# Vim: Recording a macro with an escape key press does not work correctly

Tags: vim

I have recorded a macro to the `o` register to indent and remove a space for a line, then move to the start of the next line.

The original line:

```
a : 1,
```

Keystrokes used:

```
qii<tab><esc>f<space>x+q
```

Result is exactly what I wanted:

```
    a: 1,
```

The following key strokes are recorded to the regiser: `i^I^[f x+`

Running the macro on the line (after undoing changes) results in this:

```
æ x+a : 1,
```

A few more tests reveal the following:

```
"i   i^I^[+
"o   i^I^[f x+
"p   i^I^[llx+
```

Register `i` works as expected.

Register `p` fails similar to `o` with the result looking like this:

```
ìlx+a : 1,
```

Seems that an escape key press recorded as `^[` does not exit insert mode when executing the macro.

I am on osx sierra and using vim with the terminal app.

Any ideas whats going on here and how to fix it?

Comment: You should post that as an answer, rather than editing it into your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 3):

**Cause:**

The following in my `.vimrc` caused the problem

```
" fix meta-keys which generate <Esc>a .. <Esc>z
let c='a'
while c <= 'z'
  set <M-".c.">=\e".c
  imap \e".c." <M-".c.">"
  set <M-".toupper(c).">=\e".toupper(c)
  imap \e".toupper(c)." <M-".toupper(c).">"
  let c = nr2char(1+char2nr(c))
endw
```

The above allows me to use the `<option/alt>` key in OSX as the vim `<Meta>` key. Vim is interpreting an `<Esc>` key press followed by a letter in the macro as a meta keypress.

**Solution:**

I got around the issue by remapping `<Esc>` to `<C-c>` in insert mode so it now generates `^C^C` in macros when exiting insert mode rather then `^[`.

```
inoremap <Esc> <C-c>
```

The main draw back is that it breaks arrow keys in insert mode, but since I use `hjkl` i'm fine with that.

Here are some other resources that attempt to deal with this issue:

https://github.com/vim-utils/vim-alt-mappings
https://github.com/sunaku/.vim/blob/config/plugin/escape.vim

Comment: If you haven't already, give [iTerm](https://www.iterm2.com) a try to have more flexibility, specially with meta key (option) configurations.

Comment: @sidyll Thanks for the suggestion.  From what I have seen iTerm has the same issue with `<Alt/Option>` generating a `^[` prefix.  Do you have a specific iTerm feature or fix for the issue to suggest?

Comment: Are you totally aware that **`Esc`** is not the same as **`Ctrl-C`** ?

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス I am aware. Unless I missed something, the only use for `<Esc>` or `<C-c>` while in INSERT MODE, is to exit insert mode?  When in NORMAL MODE `<Esc>` is still `<Esc>`.  Thanks for the note.

Comment: Yes they exit both the insert mode but they will prevent you from very useful functionalities take as an example this command **`4ib<Esc>`** and  **`4ib<Ctrl-C>`**

Comment: Besides `CTRL-C                  Interrupt current (search) command` ! so this remapping is useless.

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス Odly, They still seem to work correctly, 4x`b` vs 1x`b`.

Comment: Before or after the remapping ?

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス After the remapping.  I tested using `<C-[>` and `<C-c>` and get the same results as my remapped key `inoremap <Esc> <C-c>`

Comment: So you mean you got 1x`b` with both not 4x`b`. You misunderstood my previous comment no problem. So the most important is that you are aware of the differences between `ctrl-c` , `Esc` and `ctrl-[` before and after the remapping.

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス No, It works as it should. 4x`b` with `<Esc>` or `<C-[>` and 1x`b` with `<C-c>`.  With the remapping of `<Esc>` in place...

Comment: So if you remapped `Esc` to behave as `C-c` how could it be 4x`b` ?

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス I know, tested and tested, it works... Try it out and see.  I have no explanation.